# Add tr just below the last tr in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 `<tr>`'s in my HTML page. I want to get the all the HTML of the `tr` and append after the last `tr`. I also want to add a remove row after the html is added. How can we do this? Please help me.

On add row click I want to append the HTML:

**HTML**

```
<tr style="display: table-row;"  id="first_tr">

</tr>
<tr style="display: table-row;" class="is_rows_hidden" id="second_tr">
</tr>
<tr id="add_row_td">
    <td colspan="8">
        <span id="addrow"  style="float:right">[+] Add row</span>
    </td>
    <!-- here i want to add remove row after the the first addition of the HTMl -->

</tr>
<tr style="display: table-row;" id="third_tr">
</tr>
<tr style="display: table-row;"  id="fourth_tr">
</tr>
```

What I have tried is:

```
var xHtml = $('#first_tr ').map(function(){return this.outerHTML;}).get().join('');
```

How can we get all the HTML from all the `tr` and then append it just below the last `tr`?

Comment: What does "add remove row" mean?

Comment: @Jakobud sorry for that i want add and remove row feature for all the added rows

Comment: Where do you want this remove row feature added?

Comment: @Jakobud after this <span id="addrow"  style="float:right">[+] Add row</span>

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get the HTML of the last 5 tr elements in the table
var html = "";
for(i=5;i>0;i--){
  html += $('table').find('tr:nth-last-child('+i+')').wrap('').parent().html();
}

// Append whatever you want to the new row
$('table').append("<tr><td>whatever</td><td><a class='remove' href='#'>Remove Row</a></td></tr>");

// Remove row
$('table').on('click', 'a.remove', function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: how i can get the HTML of last 5 <tr> on each click of add row

Comment: FYI .html() would return the innerHTML only.. But op needs the outerHTML.

Comment: in the html var i am getting null

Answer (score 0):

Use after:

```
$('tr:last').after('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
```

I would rather use the table's id:

```
$('#tableId tr:last').after('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
```

Comment: how i can get the HTML of last 5 <tr>

Comment: Your question was how to append after the last tr and that is what I have answered

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var xTr= $('tr');
var xHtml = xTr.filter(':gt('+ (xTr.length - 6) +')').map(function(){return this.outerHTML;}).get().join('');
xTr.filter(":last").after(xHtml);
```